# NHibernate - How to return a distinct list of column entries and the count of each entry

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Is it possible to replicate the following SQL query in NHibernate?

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(Name)
FROM Table
GROUP BY Name
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to get NHibernate to execute this as a raw sql query either as it is not permitted by my current employer.

I've seen examples of returning a count of linked entities but not a count of data in the same table.

I've currently got this working by using two queries. One to get a distinct list of names and one to get the count for each name. I'd like to optimise this to a single database call.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it like this:

```
// this would be our DTO for result
public class ResultDTO
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int Count { get; set; }
}
```

This would be the query

```
// here we declare the DTO to be used for ALIASing
ResultDTO dto = null;

// here is our query
var result = session.QueryOver<Table>()
    .SelectList(l => l
        .SelectGroup(x => x.Name).WithAlias(() => dto.Name)
        .SelectCount(x => x.Name).WithAlias(() => dto.Count)
    )
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<ResultDTO>())
    .List<ResultDTO>();
```

Comment: Thanks very much. If I could give you bonus points for formatting I would!

Comment: Great to see that, sir ;) Enjoy NHibernate... still amazing tool ;)